# How to create a Col datatype in selda?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that does a `LIKE` sql query based on a parameter. I'm using Selda. I had this working before parameterizing the function:

```
selectBookQuery :: Query s (Row s GoodreadsBook)
selectBookQuery = do
  book <- select goodreadsBooks
  restrict ((book ! #title) `like` ("%Wheel of Time%"))
  return book
```

But, when I try to use the `t` param, like this:

```
selectBookQuery :: String -> Query s (Row s GoodreadsBook)
selectBookQuery t = do
  book <- select goodreadsBooks
  restrict ((book ! #title) `like` (T.pack $ "%" ++ t ++ "%"))
  return book
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Col s Text’ with actual type ‘Text’
```

I think I have a rough idea of what's happening. The string literal that I'm using in the first example is being coerced through the magic of `OverloadedStrings` to a `Col s Text`, whereas once I make it a `Text` or `String`, it doesn't get coerced into a `Col s Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Hoogle was really helpful here, when I realized I have a `Text` but needed a `Col s Text`, hoogling `Text -> Col s Text` gave me the `text` function from Selda. So all I had to change was:

```
  restrict ((book ! #title) `like` S.text (T.pack $ "%" ++ t ++ "%"))
```

where S is a qualified import of `Database.Selda`.